# Is there a way to make more space between two keyframe without grabing?

Tags: keyframes

Is there a way to make more space between two keyframe without grabing?

I need to do it many  times, so grabbing when there already a lot of keyframes in won't be efficient.

Comment: you can press b for box select, select many things and then s to scale

Comment: Well, that will make all my keyframes have more space. That's not what I want to achieve.
To be specific, I need to make space between two keyframes at certain points.